# To which side did the first Cierva autogyros fall?

Tags: aviation-history, autogyro, rotary-wing

The first Cierva autogyros, before the introduction of the flapping articulation, fell to the right when the take-off was attempted, according to witnesses. That had an explanation, as the rotor turned clockwise (seen from above) so that, when the aircraft moved forward at a certain speed, the right-side blades lost lift, the left-side blades gained lift, and the resultant torque rolled the autogyro to the right...

But, why didn't gyroscopic precession shift the reaction by 90º, pitching the nose up so that the machine fell backwards...?

Comment: [Dissymmetry of lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissymmetry_of_lift)

Comment: @Ron Beyer Dissymmetry of lift produces forces that caused the first autogyros, fitted with rigid, non-flapping blades to... roll to one side?  or to pitch up, due to gyroscopic precession...? That's the question.